# Using min_id and max_id with (new) instagram users endpoint

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

In their documentation for their new API, Instagram [says this](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/):

[image: GET /users/self/media/recent: documentation from Instagram]

Relevant points:

> - MIN_ID: Return media later than this min_id
> - MAX_ID: Return media earlier than this max_id

I want to search for media that a user posted within a certain date range. Is that possible using `min_id` and `max_id`? Or did they completely remove the ability to filter by timestamp from this new api?

Comment: I am also working on Instagram API now. The API is changed a lot. The project I am maintaining is not working with this feature.