# Instagram API /v1/users/self/media/recent with min_id doesn't performing as doc said

Tags: instagram

I am trying to fetch my post feed through Instagram API.

I can fetch all posts by using below URL:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?access_token=3316953021.24c30bf.5ecbae4a6b4840b68a499c01ba611c4d
```

I can use the same API with **max_id** to fetch earlier posts.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/3316953021/media/recent?access_token=3316953021.24c30bf.5ecbae4a6b4840b68a499c01ba611c4d&count=2&max_id=1272062614682155664_3316953021
```

However, when I followed Instagram docs to fetch post later than min_id post. It doesn't work as it promised.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?access_token=3316953021.24c30bf.5ecbae4a6b4840b68a499c01ba611c4d&count=2&min_id=1272064038816135869_3316953021
```

It supposed to get two later posts after the min_id post. But, it actually, get post start with the latest post.

Moreover, If the min_id is the latest post id, the response will start with the latest post.

Then, I found whatever I use min_id, the API will perform equivalent with below one

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?access_token=3316953021.24c30bf.5ecbae4a6b4840b68a499c01ba611c4d&count=2
```

It means the min_id never works.

Question: Any one has experience to fetch feed by set min_id? Where am I wrong in my url?

P.S. The access token is working, you can click the URL to test it.

Comment: Just a note (I'm reading this question because I've encountered the exact same issue):  it normally isn't advised to put your access token out in the open like that. If people want to test they can use their own access tokens :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you're doing anything wrong. I think this param has 'broken' with the update to IG's API recently. I've submitted an issue with them, and it would be helpful probably if you did, too.

I see similar issues being posted on StackOverflow, using the param with different endpoints. So I doubt it's 'user error.'

Comment: Like you said, I found other stackOverflow posts about this issues. Like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37777770/using-min-id-and-max-id-with-new-instagram-users-endpoint?rq=1

Comment: how do you submit issue to instagram ? Is there a public bug report tracker ?

Comment: @GiDo  Instructions are here  https://www.instagram.com/developer/support/   You do it from your developer dashboard.